# Mistake in the second derivative of implicit function

Tags: convex-analysis, implicit-differentiation, implicit-function-theorem

I have came upon this segment in a paper:
[image]

I am a bit confused. Is the formula for $\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}$ even true here? Also, it looks like they mistakingly used the notation $\frac{\partial^2 x}{\partial t^2}$

Comment: It looks plausible, albeit the hypotheses are missing. I do not see ${\partial x^2 \over \partial t^2}$ anywhere.

Comment: @copper.hat I have edited it to be $\frac{\partial^2 x}{\partial t^2}$. What I meant is that it should be a regular derivative and not a partial derivative.

Comment: @Algo A partial derivative when there is just one variable is just the usual derivative, so don't let that worry you. The formula for $x''(t)$ is correct, though I find it a bit messy to derive.